# How setup spring surf form Alfresco share with dinamic variables from a properties file

Tags: java, share, alfresco, alfresco-share, spring-surf

Hi i have write a spring surf form extensions for the software [alfresco](https://docs.alfresco.com/), in the specific a dropdown where i want to put the value on a dynamic way reading the value from `alfresco` or a properties file here the `myaction-share-amp-actions-extension-modules`:

```
<extension>
.................................................................
<config evaluator="string-compare" condition="signed">
       <forms>
            <form>
              <field-visibility>
                        ............................................
                        <show id="my_form_sign_firma.tipo"/>
                        ...................................     
              </field-visibility>
              <appearance>
.....................



<field id="my_form_sign_firma.tipo" label-id="property.form.sign.my_form_sign_firma.tipo">  
 <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/selectone.ftl">  
<control-param name="options">${value1},${value2},${value3}</control-param>
 </control>
</field>     
....................
```

or in alternative

```
....................

<field id="my_form_sign_firma.tipo" label-id="property.form.sign.my_form_sign_firma.tipo"> 
<control-param name="options">${valueX}</control-param>
 <!-- where valueX= "value1,value2,value3" -->
 </control>
</field>
....................  
                        </appearance>
                    </form>
                </forms>
            </config> 

...........................................

</extension>
```

And the bean for load the properties is set on the `share-config.xml` file:

```
<bean id="configurazioniBeanCompletoLocale" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
<property name="locations">
<list>
<value>classpath*:it/test/properties/myalfresco.properties</value>
</list>
</property>
<property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
<property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
<property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
<property name="propertiesPersister">
 <bean class="org.alfresco.config.AlfrescoPropertiesPersister" />
</property>
</bean>
```

And the properties file is set on the `share-config.xml` file:

```
classpath*:it/test/properties/myalfresco.properties
```

And the file `myalfresco.properties` contains:

```
value1=hello
value2=hi
value3=goodbye
valueX=hello,hi,goodbye
```

in alternative i can accept to use property of a specific file on alfresco if anyone know how to do for example :

`Repository/Data Dictionary/configuration.txt` with properties of a aspect "Configurator" with properties:

```
value1=hello
value2=hi
value3=goodbye
valueX=hello,hi,goodbye
```

There is a way to do one of these ?

**UPDATE:**

I will now try to write on paper a full solution on this link :
https://community.alfresco.com/thread/233246-how-setup-spring-surf-form-with-dinamic-variables-from-a-properties-file

Here you can find another example similar to this case: https://community.alfresco.com/thread/209460-dynamic-selectone-in-alfresco-share

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said by Vikash, I would suggest you to create your custom form control (put it in the `src/main/amp/config/alfresco/web-extension/site-webscripts/org /alfresco /components/form/controls/mycontrol.ftl` folder).

Inside, you will call a custom webscript you created (which will get the values of your file). This is the trivial part, I don't feel the need to show you an example.

You can look at this (simplified) example for the ftl part :

```
...
<select id="${fieldHtmlId}" name="${field.name}" tabindex="0"
     <#if field.description??>title="${field.description}"</#if>
</select>
...
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
YAHOO.util.Event.onContentReady("${fieldHtmlId}", function ()
{
    Alfresco.util.Ajax.jsonGet({
        url: encodeURI(Alfresco.constants.PROXY_URI + '/myserviceuri'),
        successCallback:
        {
            fn: function loadWebscript_successCallback(response, config)
            {
                var obj = eval('(' + response.serverResponse.responseText + ')');
                if (obj)
                {
                    for (i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
                            var newOption = document.createElement('option');
                            newOption.value = obj[i].id;
                            newOption.text = obj[i].name;
                            YAHOO.util.Dom.get("${fieldHtmlId}").options.add(newOption);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });

}, this);
//]]></script>
```

You can then use it this way :

```
<field id="my_form_sign_firma.tipo" label-id="property.form.sign.my_form_sign_firma.tipo">  
 <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/mycontrol.ftl">
 </control>
</field>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use your custom ftl file as form control

Give template path to your custom ftl file in share form

```
 <form>
         <appearance>
            <field id="cm:name">
               <control template="/my-textfield.ftl" />
            </field>
         </appearance>
      </form>
```

Refer this [Documentation](https://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/tasks/forms-custom-formcontrol.html)

Comment: yes i have tried that , but can i retrieve the properties file from the .ftl file? i mean i don't have found a working javascript code for retrieve the file properties from my template.ftl, if you can show me a example that can be the perfect solution.